# Is the squid giant axon the fastest conducting unmyelinated axon known?

Tags: neuroscience, zoology

The conduction velocity of the squid giant axon can reach 30 m/s. Is there any known example of an even faster conducting unmyelinated axons?

Answer (score 6):

The conductance velocity in the unmyelinated axon has been calculated and measured to be proportional to the square root of the axon diameter (see for example: [Rushton, 1951](http://jp.physoc.org/content/115/1/101.full.pdf+html)). Since the giant axon is, well, *giant*, it conducts much faster than others. AFAIK, all other large neurons studied are myelinated. Maybe try to find bigger squids! ;)

Comment: Did he show that the diameter is the _only_ factor?

Comment: No, that's just *one* factor, but thought to be more variable than others, such as membrane capacitance or cytoplasm resistance, that are less variable among different cell types.

Comment: +1 for answer and making me laugh. Giant axons are giant, man!